Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ only solution to equation $\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k f(x+k+1)=f(x)-x^{n+1}f(x+n+1)$?
From this question and the comment made by @ClaudeLeibovici after the answer given by @GEdgar, it turns out that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ is a solution to the following equation for any integer $n$:
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k f(x+k+1)=f(x)-x^{n+1}f(x+n+1), x > 0} $$
with $f(1)=1$.
Does this equation characterize the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$, or are there other solutions to the above equation?
We may first focus on continuous functions to simlify the problem.

Looks scale invariant, right?  So if $f$ is a solution, so is $\lambda f$ for any constant $\lambda$.

More broadly, the functional equation only appears to link $f(x)$ to ${f(x+n)}$ for some integers $n$.  Thus, I would think you could make wild solutions by taking different $\lambda$ for each coset.  Of course you could avoid this by adding some initial condition, like $f(1)=1$, and imposing some continuity requirements.

@lulu thanks! I just clarified it the OP following your suggestion.

Any function with $x f(x+1) = f(x)$ satisfies this.  [Prove it by induction on $n$?] Of course $1/\Gamma(x)$ is an example, but there are many others.  Take $f$ arbitrary on $(0,1]$ and extend to $(0,+\infty)$ using that functional equation.

@GEdgar Where can I find all the solutions to $xf(x+1)=f(x)$? Wolfram returns only $\frac{c}{\Gamma(x)}$.

All solutions were described in the comment above.  Take $f$ arbitrary on $(0,1]$ ..."

@GEdgar Thanks! Is there any requirement that distinguishes $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ from the other solutions?
